# "Server failed to authenticate the request" when attempting to make an Azure REST API call on my data lake storage gen2 using Ruby

Tags: ruby, azure, powershell

I want to be able to access my Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account through a ruby script so that I can add files/directories.

**sniff adls gen2 storage api calls**

http://sql.pawlikowski.pro/2019/03/09/how-to-sniff-adls-gen2-storage-rest-api-calls-to-azure-using-azure-storage-explorer/

**connecting to azure data lake storage gen2 from powershell using rest api**

http://sql.pawlikowski.pro/2019/03/10/connecting-to-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-from-powershell-using-rest-api-a-step-by-step-guide/

I have tried following the above guides trying to replicate the powershell scripts in ruby code. I have also tried both keys from the storage account access keys and I still get the same error.

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'securerandom'
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'digest' 

access_key = "ACCESS KEY HERE"
shared_key = encode_string(access_key)

storage_account_name = 'r1dltest'
target_filesystem = 'datalake'

uri_string = "https://#{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/#{target_filesystem}?directory='/'&maxresults=5000&recursive=false&resource=filesystem"

## Parse URI
puts("> Parsing URI: #{uri_string}")
uri = URI.parse(uri_string)

## PUT request.
puts("> Setting up PUT request.")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)

## Set headers.
puts("> Setting authorization headers")
puts ("Auth Header Key: #{storage_account_name}:#{shared_key}")
request["Authorization"] = "SharedKey #{storage_account_name}:#{shared_key}" 
request["x-ms-version"] = "2018-11-09"

## Options
req_options = {
    use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

## Execute request.
puts("> Executing request...")
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
end

puts(response.body)
```

```rb
def encode_string(key)
    n = ""
    method = "GET"
    date = ""
    version = "2018-11-09"
    storage_account_name = "saname"
    file_system_name = "fsname"

    stringToSign = method + n
    stringToSign += n # Content-Encoding
    stringToSign += n # Content-Language
    stringToSign += n # Content-Length
    stringToSign += n # Content-MD5
    stringToSign += n # Content-Type
    stringToSign += n # Date
    stringToSign += n # If-Modified-Since
    stringToSign += n # If-Match
    stringToSign += n # If-None-Match
    stringToSign += n # If-Unmodified-Since
    stringToSign += n # Range

    stringToSign += "x-ms-date:" + n +
                    "x-ms-version: #{version}" + n
    stringToSign += "/#{storage_account_name}/#{file_system_name}" + n +
                    "recursive: true" + n
                    "resource: filesystem" + n
    puts(stringToSign)

    shared_key = Base64.decode64(key)    
    hashedKey = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', shared_key, stringToSign)    
    signedString = Base64.strict_encode64(Digest::SHA256.digest(hashedKey))

    return signedString
end
```

**output from my code.**

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag this `PowerShell` ?

Comment: Well my problem involves translating some powershell script from the links I included into ruby. or at least an explanation on how they work so I can be able to replicate in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ruby. But, as far as I now, there is a newline between each string to sign. In official documentation, you should use '\n' which represent a new line. However, you just used a null string.

And, you also forgot to set the x-ms-date header value.

```
stringToSign += "x-ms-date:" + n +
                "x-ms-version: #{version}" + n
```

By the way, Microsoft officially suggests developers use Azure AD for authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lakes-store-authentication-using-azure-active-directory